# Boundedness of Helmholtz projection

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let's cosider the Helmoltz projection $P$ into solenoidal subspace defined as
$$P=I-\nabla div\Delta^{-1}$$
What can I say about its boundedness as an operator in $H^s(\mathbb{R^3})$?

Comment: Is $s$ just a real number or it is an positive integer?

Comment: @wisher It's a positive real number